# Put lastest item's data in trigger name

Tags: triggers, macros, zabbix

I got a problem with some feature of Zabbix, I think i did not understood all. I hope some of you can help me !
So, I Want to put in the trigger name the latest data sending by "zabbix_sender". I had to monitoring certificate, and I want that all users  see easily the day remaining in the trigger name on my dasbhoard.

{ITEM.LASTVALUE<0-9>}
{ITEM.VALUE<0-9>}

I want thing like that : "trigger name certificat xxx 17 days remaining
With "17" use thing like {ITEM.VALUE<0-9>}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{ITEM.LASTVALUE<1-9>}` macro is supported in Trigger names and descriptions, see [documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.2/manual/appendix/macros/supported_by_location).

You can also enable "*show latest values*" in your problem view. This will show latest values on all rows.

*Edit*: this macro is now subject to discussion for its differences between version 3 and 4, see [Zabbix forum discussion](https://www.zabbix.com/forum/zabbix-help/367036-item-lastvalue-vs-item-value-in-zabbix-4-0).